# Pointer vs Return

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

Which is faster when assigning a variable via a method, to return a variable, or to point to a variable?

*Case 1*:

**Function Declaration**

```
void foo(int* number)
{
    *number = 5;
}
```

**Usage**

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    function(&number);
    cout << "Number: " << number;
}
```

*Case 2*:

**Function Declaration**

```
int foo()
{
    int number = 5;
    return number;
}
```

**Usage**

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    number = function();
    cout << "Number: " << number;
}
```

*PS: In case 2, I created a variable and returned it instantly. I know this doesn't make sense, but this is the closest example I can find for the situation I'm dealing with, since I'm initializing an actual object, which requires creating the object first, editing it, then returning it*

Comment: "Better" in what sense?

Comment: You missed references! `void foo(int& i) { i = 5; } int main() { int x; foo(x); return x; }`

Comment: Return the value. Unless you have very good reasons to do otherwise.

Comment: In what context? I wouldn't use pointers in your example here, but that doesn't mean pointers are never "better".

Comment: Better, as in which is faster.

Comment: This is C++, and as such I'm struggling to think of a reason it is *ever* better to pass a parameter by address to a formal pointer parameter). In C, its another story, but blessed is the *reference* in C++. (and in your specific example, return the value. If you're function must populate data *and* has reason to use the return value for something *else*, use a reference (and those times better be rare).

Comment: if you only wanted to modify the variable, rather than overwriting it completely, then you could pass a reference or pointer.

Comment: In that particular toy example, return by value is faster than pass by pointer. That does not mean that it will be more efficient in all cases, or easier to read or ...

Comment: void foo(int* number) is certainly no good, make it void foo(int& number), but that is still ugly.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the cost of copying the variable.  For primitive types, return a value.
For more complex types consider passing in a reference, or take a look at the C++11 move semantics.

Comment: There's (N)RVO, too, which applies a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of using output parameters (Case 1) is it gives you the ability to have a function 'return' multiple values:

```
void foo (int* x, int* y)
{
    *x = 5;
    *y = 4;
}
```

But like everyone said in the comments, this doesn't matter in C++ as much as C. 
Generally returns are far more readable and make your program's logic well defined and 
easy to follow. In C++, stick to returns or references.

Comment: even more preferrable to raw pointers would be references...

Comment: Yeah, I said that at the end, since this is C++. I <3 references.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you should choose which to use on your needs rather than on performance.

Do you have multiple outputs? -> Use pointers

Is an input going to be an output -> Might as well use pointers

It's more difficult with these two scenarios to return a variable.
Other than that, performance-wise, it's only nice to use a variable when the variable is super complex, that way, you're only passing in a pointer instead of that super complex object. But any performance gain is negligible other than that.